# Count SQL results form first query in second query in single statement

Tags: mysql, sql

Here's my SQL statement:

```
(select * from items
where items.created > curdate() - interval 2 week 
order by items.created desc limit 0,10000000000)

union all

(select * from items
where items.created < curdate() - interval 2 week 
order by items.popularity desc limit 0,15)
```

I'm trying to figure out a way to limit the entire result of the query to a certain number (say 25). As it is now, this result returns an unlimited number for the first result (which is what I want), then returns 15 for the second result. I want to be able to limit the whole query so that even if the first result returns 8, the second result returns 17, total 25.

I believe to do this, I have to use count() somehow in the first query, then subtract that from the total I want and use that number as the 2nd query's limit. I have no idea how this is done.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another select:

```
select * from
(

  (select * from items
  where items.created > curdate() - interval 2 week 
  order by items.created desc limit 0,10000000000)

  union all

  (select * from items
  where items.created < curdate() - interval 2 week 
  order by items.popularity desc)

) uniond_tables_alias
limit 25
```

The `uniond_tables_alias` is an alias for the uniond section, you can choose any name you want.

Comment: Sweet, this works (I'll accept once SO lets me). One small change you might want to make for future readers: I had to take out the limit 0,15 from the second select, because it was still limiting that one.

Comment: Oops, one more edit. I just discovered the order by for the second statement doesn't work without a limit, so I just put limit 0,10000000000 in both selects.

Comment: @Jake: Weird. I took some table with ids, and asked this query: `select * from (SELECT * FROM tsite WHERE mod(id,2) = 1 limit 1 union SELECT * FROM tsite WHERE mod(id,2) = 0 order by id desc/asc) z limit 4` and I've got the correct records in the correct order.

Comment: I'm not sure what causes it, but you can see that in a previous question I asked relating to this same statement, the answer acknowledges the need for the limits: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7301571/mysql-ordering-a-date-range-to-the-beginning-then-ordering-everything-else-by-o

Answer (score 2):

Here is the required query -

```
select *
from 
((select * from items
where items.created > curdate() - interval 2 week 
order by items.created desc limit 0,10000000000)

union all

(select * from items
where items.created < curdate() - interval 2 week 
order by items.popularity desc)) t
limit 0,25
```

Answer (score 1):

No need for nested queries, simply do:

```
(select * from items
where items.created > curdate() - interval 2 week 
order by items.created desc)                      # remove LIMIT here

UNION ALL

(select * from items
where items.created < curdate() - interval 2 week 
order by items.popularity desc)                   # remove LIMIT here

LIMIT 25;                                         # add LIMIT here
```

This'll return the 25 first results from the first SELECT if there's at least 25. Otherwise it will fill up the remaining results with the second SELECT results until the limit of 25 is reached.

Comment: sometimes it will sometimes it won't. The only guaranteed ordering is what you explicitly put into an ORDER BY.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 1 AS sortkey, * from items ....
UNION ALL
SELECT 2 AS sortkey, * from items ....

ORDER BY sortkey, etc.
LIMIT 25
```